# Rebasing a local branch from develop

Tags: git, phpstorm, rebase

I want to rebase a feature branch from develop. I am using PhpStorm Git integration and I have 2 different develop branches:

```
refs/remotes/origin/develop
refs/heads/develop
```

In order to do not mess up things, which one do I have to choose to rebase?

Comment: `refs/remotes`  is your remote branch reference.
You just need to run `git rebase develop`  on your feature branch

Answer (score 99, accepted):

I don't know the phpstorm interface for Git, but in the command line I'd do the following:

- `git checkout develop`
- `git pull origin develop` -> this fetches the remote version of the develop branch and merges it (or rebases it, depending on your pull strategy) into/onto your local branch. This way the local and the remote versions of develop are the same
- `git checkout feature-brach`
- `git rebase develop`

If there are any conflicts - resolve them. After that you can create a pull request against `develop`.

Comment: It is not mentioned that in the end you will have to do the 'git push --force' to push your newly formed history changes on to the remote. Without this, git will rejected my 'git push origin feature-branch'.

Comment: A more gentle way to push your changes is: `git push --force-with-lease`

Answer (score 12):

When you are at your branch, where you have committed changes:
Do the following:

1. `git fetch`
2. `git rebase origin/develop`
   In case of any conflicts, please fix them.
   Then,
3. `git add .`
4. `git rebase --continue`