# Strange error during compilation - Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I recently moved to Angular 9. 
In addition to the fact that my feature branch is not working after the rebase, I tried to switch to develop and update it (using pull origin develop). Everything seemed ok, instead I have only one error that I can't understand:
[image]

---

What does it mean `ERROR in Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`?
I can't decipher it so alone, in nothing...!
Initially I thought it didn't affect anything, and instead when I open the browser I found this error:
[image]

Honestly I don't know what to do. I hope someone knows something about it, being Angular 9 very new.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
I compile using `npm run start`

Comment: In your app find all the lines having `someArray.push` and make sure that the array exists before pushing new elements into it.

Comment: But how do I find it? The linter however does not deal with underlining the undefined elements...!  I did `ctrl + alt + f`, I found all the `push` of the project, but if they are not underlined...!

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/17109

Comment: Please add the output of `ng version`. Most likely you want to upgrade angular-specific packages to `9.0.4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stay on develop and do:

```
git pull origin develop
```

then

```
npm i
```

Probably "from above" they added things that need to be installed locally, and therefore `npm i` solves your life.
Once done, go back to your feature branch and [rebase with develop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50736080/rebasing-a-local-branch-from-develop).

Comment: Might also want to nuke `node_modules` before running `npm i`, just to make sure it's all freshly installed.